# vim autocmd hook after performing a search in the text?

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor, vi

I had a look at the list of events autocmd can handle, but I could not find one about search queries.

What I would like to do is to add some custom behavior after each text search is performed. I was able to remap the `*` command with this command:

```
map * *<F11>
```

In this case I mapped `<F11>` to a `:call My_function()` which will do something with the search pattern contained in `@/`.

But I still need to add my custom behavior to the `/` command, which is more complicated, as before it's completed it's getting the input search pattern.

Do you have any hint on how to proceed? Can I use `autocmd`? Or maybe is there a `map` trick?

Comment: More explanation please with an example

Comment: just added some more context; further details would side-track the question to other details

Comment: What sort of Custom behaviour? If you don't hide, I can tell an answer it :D

Comment: IMHO the questions on stackoverflow should be as "atomic" as possible to descrive the problem in the more comprehensive way. Anyways, even if this is not going to help responding to my question, I will tell you my idea just to satisfy your curiosity: I am building an external program that is going to search in a directory with many source files the token that I am searching in the current file that I am editing. It's almost done, and it's very cool.

Answer (score 1):

An (bad) way to do it would be to remap the <kbd>return</kbd> key (and the <kbd>esc</kbd> key)
when <kbd>/</kbd> is pressed, something like that:

```
function! MyCustomBehaviour()
    echo "Oui oui"
endf

function! UnmapSearch()
    cunmap <cr>
    cunmap <esc>
endf

function! MapSearch()
    cnoremap <cr> <cr>:call UnmapSearch()<bar>call MyCustomBehaviour()<cr>
    cnoremap <silent> <esc> <c-c>:call UnmapSearch()<cr>
endf

noremap / :<c-u>call MapSearch()<cr>/
```

It's a bad way because it's quite buggy : if you press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> while editing the
search, it won't unmap `<cr>` and `<esc>`, then the next time you will enter `:` (command-line) mode,
the mappings will still be active... That's a problem that can't be solved (`<c-c>` can't be
remapped).

It's also a bad way because remapping directly the `/` key this way, IMO, is not a good practice.

But... This was the only solution I found some times ago to half-solve this problem.

Another workaround (the one I finally choose) can be written in one line :

```
cnoremap <c-cr> <cr>:call MyCustomBehaviour()<cr>
```